# Progressive Number Sequencing in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that can vary in length, I want to add a column ('Count') that starts at 0 and increments by 1 every 25th row.

I have googled and tried a few solutions but nothings gets me anywhere close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydf = ...
mydf$Count = floor(seq(0,nrow(mydf)-1) / 25)
```

Comment: Valentin, 

Thanks for the suggestion. 

This works to a certain extent but I actually realised I needed each 25 rows to be numbers differently. When I adjusted your code to / 26. Then the first 25 rows are numbered 0 but the next 26 rows are numbered 1.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding correctly here is the "/ 26" change fixing it? otherwise what is exactly the problem with the code above?

Comment: @DenJJ, I think I fixed it, there was a bug in my code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(51))
df$Count <- cumsum(rep(c(rep(0, 24), 1), length.out = nrow(df)))
```

If not, given the description of your problem, it might be easily adaptable.

Comment: Thanks Rui, this certainly got me closer!

It worked for the first 25th but was then started to update on the 26th.. 27th row etc

Any thoughts?

Comment: My understanding of the problem is that for the first 24 elements you want zero. Then from the 25th to the 49th, a one. Then from the 50th to the 74th, a two. Etc. is this correct?